# NSIS CreateShortCut: Shortcuts order on Start menu

Tags: installation, nsis, shortcut

I am using NSIS to create an installer for one of my apps, and I am using this code to create shortcuts on the start menu:

```
;create start-menu items
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\myFolder"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\myFolder\app.lnk" "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\app.exe" 0
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\myFolder\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" 0
```

It works, but the Uninstaller shortcut on the start menu > myFolder appears before the app.exe shortcut.

Is there a way to control the order of the shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the installation order is ignored, Windows arranges them automatically. In older Windows versions the start menu has a context menu option for ordering them alphabetically, but newer versions order them automatically.

Answer (score -2):

here is the CreateShorCut usage

> CreateShorCut link.lnk target.file
>   [parameters [icon.file
>   [**icon_index_number** [start_options
>   [keyboard_shortcut [description]]]]]]

did you tryed :

```
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\myFolder"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\myFolder\app.lnk" "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\app.exe" 0
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\myFolder\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" 1
```